# how to insert values of foreign key constraint from other table?

Tags: php, mysql

table name `category` 
and table columns

```
1) cat_id (primary key)
2) cat_title
```

the other table is `book`
and the columns are

```
1) book_id (primary key)
2) book_title
3) cat_id(foreign key)
```

for the foreign key constraint i was trying the following query:

```
INSERT INTO book VALUES (1,'new book',(SELECT `cat_title` FROM `categroy` WHERE `cat_id`=3))
```

it is not working. is their anybody to please tell how can i improve this query so that it can come into order. help shell highly be appriciated

Comment: If you really have some value in category table against cat_id=3 then your query is fine

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your query.

First, you always use "1" as your new key. It will create an error if you already have that key in your book table. You could use NULL there.

Second, there is a typo on "FROM categroy". Should be: "FROM category".

Comment: please suggest me for the second problem